# ISNULL with SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to use `ISNULL` with all columns of a table.

Like this

```
SELECT ISNULL(* , 'NA') FROM #tbl
```

I know its a wrong way I have to specify each column name separately to use `ISNULL`.

But in my case `#tbl` is a temporary table and columns are created dynamically

like this:

```
EXEC ('ALTER TABLE #tbl ADD [' + @bno + '] varchar(30)')
```

Due to this I can't use column names in select query because column names are always different.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your dynamic SQL to:

```
EXEC ('ALTER TABLE #tbl ADD [' + @bno + '] varchar(30) NULL DEFAULT(''NA'')')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get fields of your temprary table from the tempdb.sys.columns table then iterate over these:

```
select c.*
from tempdb.sys.columns c
inner join tempdb.sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name like '#TableName%'
```